# Attempt to free non-allocated memory without using free()

Tags: c, memory

I wrote program which adds and subtracts positive and negative numbers which are strings. Add() function test, which limits heap size to 6 bytes throws error: SIGHEAP for input data like for example: `add("101", "242", &result);` .
Function add() in this test should allocate memory properly and return 0.
None of my functions have function which can free memory and because of that I don't understand what causes this error. Attempt seems to happen while leaving a2() because I called another error just before leaving a2() and just after. Test throws sigheap only when the other error is before leaving the function. Here are test, functions and main() :

```
    test_file_write_limit_setup(33554432);
    rldebug_reset_limits();
    rldebug_heap_set_global_limit(6);
    
    //
    // -----------
    //void UTEST138(void)
{
    // informacje o teście
    test_start(138, "Checking correctness of function add(), heap size is 6 bytes", __LINE__);

    // uwarunkowanie zasobów - pamięci, itd...
    test_file_write_limit_setup(33554432);
    rldebug_reset_limits();
    rldebug_heap_set_global_limit(6);
    
    //
    // -----------
    //
    

                char *result;
                const char *expected_result = "505";        
                printf("#####START#####");
                int err_code = add("237", "268", &result);
                printf("#####END#####\\n");
                test_error(err_code == 0, "Function add() should return 0, and returned %d", err_code);
        
                onerror_terminate(); // stopping tests if for example sth is very wrong about the code
        
                if (!0)
                {
                    test_error(result != NULL, "Function add() should assign result under new allocated memory adress but assigned NULL");
                    onerror_terminate(); //stopping tests if for example sth is very wrong about the code
                    test_error(strcmp(result, expected_result) == 0, "Value calculated by add() is wrong should be '%s', and is '%s'", expected_result, result);
                    free(result);
                }
                test_no_heap_leakage();
                onerror_terminate(); // 

            
    //
    // -----------
    //

  
    rldebug_reset_limits();
    test_file_write_limit_restore();
    
    test_ok();

}
```

functions:

```
//function which decides where to pass numbers to add them properly
  int add(const char* number1, const char* number2, char** result) {
  if (number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL) {
      return 1;
  }
  if (validate(number1) != 0 || validate(number2) != 0) {
      return 1;
  }
  int r = 0;

  r = sign_check(number1, number2);
  if(r==0) { return a2(number1, number2, result, r); }
  if (r == 1) { return s2(number2, number1, result); }
  if (r == 2) { return s2(number1, number2, result); }
  if (r == 3) { return a2(number1, number2, result, r); }
  return 0;
}

//function which decides where to pass numbers to subtract them properly
int subtract(const char* number1, const char* number2, char** result) {
  if (number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL) {
      return 1;
  }
  if (validate(number1) != 0|| validate(number2) != 0) {
      return 1;
  }
  int r = 0;

  r = sign_check(number1, number2);
  if(r==0){ return s2(number1, number2, result); }
  if (r == 1) { return a2(number1, number2, result, r); }
  if(r==2){ return a2(number1, number2, result, r); }
  if(r==3){ return s2(number2, number1, result); }
  return 0;
}

//function which checks if number is proper
int validate(const char* number) {
  if (number == NULL) {
      return -1;
  }
  int a = 20, b = 10, i = 0;
  a += 20; a += 10; a--; a--; b = a; b += 10; b--;
  if (*(number + 0) == '0' && *(number + 1) != '\x0') { return 2; }
  for (i = 0; *(number + i) != '\x0'; i++) {
      if (i != 0 && *(number + i) == '-') { return 2; }
      if ((*(number + i) > 57 || *(number + i) < 48) && *(number + i) != '-') {
          return 2;
      }
  }
  if (i == 1 && *number == '-') { return 2; }
  if (i == 0) { return 2; }
  return 0;
}
//Function which checks which number absolute value is bigger
int c2(const char* number1, const char* number2) {
  if (number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL) { return 2; }
  int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, i11 = 0, i22 = 0;

  for (i1 = 0; *(number1 + i1) != '\x0'; i1++) {
  }
  for (i2 = 0; *(number2 + i2) != '\x0'; i2++) {
  }
  if (*number1 == '-') { --i1, ++i11; }
  if (*number2 == '-') { --i2, ++i22; }
  if (i1 == i2) {
      for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++, i11++, i22++) {
          if (*(number1 + i11) > * (number2 + i22)) { return 1; }
          if (*(number2 + i22) > * (number1 + i11)) { return -1; }
      }
      return 0;
  }
  else if (i1 > i2) { return 1; }
  else { return -1; }
}
//Function which compares length of numbers
int compare2(const char* number1, int* i1, const char* number2, int* i2) {
  if (number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL || i1 == NULL || i2 == NULL) { return 2; }
  for (*i1 = 0; *(number1 + *i1) != '\x0'; (*i1)++) {
  }
  for (*i2 = 0; *(number2 + *i2) != '\x0'; (*i2)++) {
  }
  if (*i1 == *i2) {
      return 0;
  }
  else if (*i1 > * i2) { return 1; }
  else { return -1; }
  return 0;
}
//Function which checks if numbers are positive or negative
int sign_check(const char* number1, const char* number2) {
  if (*number1 != '-' && *number2 != '-') { return 0; }
  if (*number1 == '-' && *number2 != '-') { return 1; }
  if (*number1 != '-' && *number2 == '-') { return 2; }
  if (*(number1) == '-' && *(number2) == '-') { return 3; }
  return 0;
}

//Function which subtracts numbers given by function add()
int s2(const char* number1, const char* number2, char** result) {
  if (number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL) {
      return 1;
  }
  if (validate(number1) != 0 || validate(number2) != 0) {
      return 1;
  }
  int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, x = 0, suma = 0, i = 0,temp=0, a = 20, ret = 0, true_size = 0, i11 = 0, i22 = 0, zero_counter=0;
  a += 20; a += 10; a -= 2;
  compare2(number1, &i1, number2, &i2);
  i11 = i1, i22 = i2;
  ret = c2(number1, number2);
  char* num1=(char*)number1, * num2=(char*)number2, t;
  if (ret == -1) {
  num2 = (char*)number1; num1 = (char*)number2; 
  temp = i1;
  i1 = i2;
  i2 = temp;
  }
 
  i1--, i2--;
  i11 = i1, i22 = i2;
while ((i1 != -1 && *(num1 + i1) != '-') && (*(num2 + i2) != '-' && i2 != -1)) {
   t = *(num1 + i1);
   if (x > 0) {
          if (t == '0') {
              t = '9';
          }
          else {
              --t;
              x = 0;
          }
      }

      if (t < *(num2 + i2)) {
          t += 10; x++;
      }
      suma = (t - a) - (*(num2 + i2) - a);
      t = abs(suma) + a;
      if (t == '0') { ++zero_counter; }
      else { zero_counter=0; }
      i++, i1--, i2--;
  }
  if (i1 > i2) {
      while (i1 != -1&& *(num1 + i1) != '-') {
          t = *(num1 + i1);
          if (x > 0) {
              if (t == '0') {
                  t = '9';
              }
              else {
                  --t;
                  x = 0;
              }
          }
          suma = t - a;
          t = abs(suma) + a;
          if (t == '0') { ++zero_counter; }
          else{ zero_counter=0; }
          i++, i1--;
      }
  }

  int limit = i - zero_counter;
  true_size = limit+1;
  if (ret == -1) ++true_size;
  *result = malloc(true_size);
  if (*result == NULL) { return 3; }
  i1 = i11, i2 = i22, i=0;
  int iter = true_size - 2;

  while ((i1 != -1 && *(num1 + i1) != '-') && (*(num2 + i2) != '-' && i2 != -1)) {
      if (i >= limit) { break; }
      t = *(num1 + i1);
      if (x > 0) {
          if (t == '0') {
              t = '9';
          }
          else {
              --t;
              x = 0;
          }
      }

      if (t < *(num2 + i2)) {
          t += 10; x++;
      }
      suma = (t - a) - (*(num2 + i2) - a);
      *(*result+iter) = abs(suma) + a;
      i++, i1--, i2--, iter--;
  }
  if (i1 > i2) {
      while (i1 != -1 && *(num1 + i1) != '-') {
          if (i >= limit) { break; }
          t = *(num1 + i1);
          if (x > 0) {
              if (t == '0') {
                  t = '9';
              }
              else {
                  --t;
                  x = 0;
              }
          }
          suma = t - a;
          *(*result + iter) = abs(suma) + a;
          i++, i1--, iter--;
      }
  }


  if (ret == -1) { *(*result) = '-'; }
  *(*result + true_size - 1) = '\x0';
  return 0;

}



//Function which adds numbers given by function add()
int a2(const char* number1, const char* number2, char** result, int r) {
  if (number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL) {
      return 1;
  }
  if (validate(number1) != 0|| validate(number2) != 0) {
      return 1;
  }
  int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, x = 0, suma = 0, i = 0, a = 20, true_size=0, subst_size=0, i11=0, i22=0;
  a += 20; a += 10; a -= 2;
  compare2(number1, &i1, number2, &i2);
  i11 = i1, i22 = i2;
  if (i1 >= i2) subst_size = i1 + 3;
  else subst_size = i2 + 3;
  i1--; i2--;

  while ((i1 != -1&&*(number1+i1)!='-')&&(*(number2 + i2) != '-' && i2 != -1)) {
      suma = *(number1 + i1) - a + *(number2 + i2) - a;
      if (x > 0) { suma++; }
      x = 0;
      i++;
      if (suma >= 10) { x++; }
      i1--; i2--;
  }
  if (i1 == i2) {
      if (x > 0) { i++; }
  }
  else if (i1 > i2) {
      while (i1 != -1&& *(number1 + i1) != '-') {
          suma = *(number1 + i1) - a;
          if (x > 0) { suma++; }
          x = 0;
          if (suma >= 10) { x++; }
          i++;
          i1--;
      }
      if (x > 0) { i++;}
  }
  else if (i2 > i1) {
      while (i2 != -1&& *(number2 + i2) != '-') {
          suma = *(number2 + i2) - a;
          if (x > 0) { suma++; }
          x = 0;
          if (suma >= 10) { x++; }
          i++;
          i2--;
      }
      if (x > 0) { i++; }
  }
  int diff = 0, auxi = 1;
  x = 0;
  if (r == 1 || r == 3) { true_size = i + 2; auxi++; }
  else { true_size = i + 1; }

  *result = (char*)malloc(true_size);
  if (*result == NULL) { if (true_size >= subst_size) { return 3; } else { *result = (char*)malloc(subst_size); diff = true_size - subst_size; true_size = subst_size; } if (*result == NULL) { return 3; } }
  i1 = i11-1, i2=i22-1;
  i = 0;
 // if (diff <= auxi) { return 2; }
  while ((i1 != -1 && *(number1 + i1) != '-') && (*(number2 + i2) != '-' && i2 != -1)) {
      if (i >= true_size) { break; }
      suma = *(number1 + i1) - a + *(number2 + i2) - a;
      if (x > 0) { suma++; }
      x = 0;

      if (i >= diff) { *(*result + i) = (suma % 10) + a; i++; }

      if (suma >= 10) { x++; }
      i1--; i2--;
  }
  if (i1 == i2) {
     
      if (x > 0 && i < true_size&& i >= diff) { *(*result + i) = x + a;   i++; }
  }
  else if (i1 > i2) {
      while (i1 != -1 && *(number1 + i1) != '-') {
          if (i >= true_size) { break; }
          suma = *(number1 + i1) - a;
          if (x > 0) { suma++; }
          x = 0;
          if (suma >= 10) { x++; }
          if (i >= diff) { *(*result + i) = (suma % 10) + a; i++; }
          i1--;
      }
      if (x > 0 && i < true_size && i >= diff) { *(*result + i) = x + a;  i++; }
  }
  else if (i2 > i1) {
      while (i2 != -1 && *(number2 + i2) != '-') {
          if (i >= true_size) { break; }
          suma = *(number2 + i2) - a;
          if (x > 0) { suma++; }
          x = 0;
          if (suma >= 10) { x++; }
          if (i >= diff) { *(*result + i) = (suma % 10) + a; i++; }
          i2--;
      }
      if (x > 0&& i < true_size&&i >= diff) { *(*result + i) = x + a;  i++; }
  }
  if (r == 1 || r == 3) {
  *(*result + true_size-2) = '-';
  *(*result + true_size - 1) = '\x0';
  }
  else{
  *(*result + true_size - 1) = '\x0';
  }
  i = true_size - 2;
  int q = 0;
  int v = i;
  char temp;
  for (; i > v / 2; i--, q++) {
      temp = *(*result + q);
      *(*result + q) = *(*result + i);
      *(*result + i) = temp;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Function main():

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char* str = (char*)malloc(200);
    if (str == NULL) { printf("Failed to allocate memory"); return 8; }
    printf("input striiing up to 1000 signs:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if (i <= 199) {
            if (scanf("%c", str + i) == 0) {
                printf("Incorrect input");
              free(str);
                return 1;
            }

            if (*(str + i) == '\n') {
                *(str + i) = '\x0';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //   c = 0;
    char* tab = (char*)malloc(200);
    if (tab == NULL) { printf("Failed to allocate memory"); free(str); return 8; }
    printf("input striing up to 1000 signs:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if (i <= 199) {
            if (scanf("%c", tab + i) == 0) {
                printf("Incorrect input");
               free(str); free(tab);
                return 1;
            }

            if (*(tab + i) == '\n') {
                *(tab + i) = '\x0';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    *(tab + 199) = '\x0';

    if (validate(tab) != 0|| validate(str) != 0) {
        printf("Incorrect input");
        free(str); free(tab);
        return 1;
    }

    char* T = NULL;

    int ret = add(str, tab, &T);
    if (ret > 0) {
        if (ret == 3) { printf("Failed to allocate memory"); return 8; }
        else {
            printf("Incorrect input");
            free(tab); free(str);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    char* T2 = NULL;

    ret = subtract(str, tab, &T2);

    if (ret > 0) {
        if (ret == 3) { printf("Failed to allocate memory"); return 8; }
        else {
            printf("Incorrect input");
           free(tab); free(str);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", T);
    printf("%s", T2);
    free(T2); free(T);
    free(tab); free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: Valgrind doesn't show any errors

Comment: A lot of relevant code is missing. First of all, with what parameters is `add` called? Are you sure they point to legal data objects? Secondly, I don't see the definitions of functions `validate`, `sign_check` and `compare2`, all of which are called by `add` and `a2`.

Comment: Added all the missing functions and main() now.

Comment: The code presented is far too much and far too complex.  We expect the code supporting a question to take the form of a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

In `main()` you allocate 2 arrays of `200` bytes, prompt for up to 1000 digits and run loops to an index up to `100000`... Not a good start to test under memory allocation constraints.

Indeed it is unclear how you try and limit the heap available for the `add()` and `sub()` computations.

Your code is extremely complicated, the presentation and indentation is inconsistent and the ubiquitous cramming of multiple instructions on the same line make it too difficult to follow. Adding and subtracting bignums encoded as strings should be much simpler.

Also note that `printf` may allocate and free memory with `malloc()` and `free()`. This might explain your observations.

Here is a simpler approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *bigadd(const char *a, const char *b) {
    size_t alen = strlen(a);
    size_t blen = strlen(b);
    size_t clen = (alen > blen) ? alen : blen;
    char *c = malloc(clen + 2);
    if (c != NULL) {
        size_t i = clen;
        int carry = 0;
        c[i] = '\0';
        while (i > 0) {
            int digit = (alen ? a[--alen] - '0' : 0) +
                        (blen ? b[--blen] - '0' : 0) + carry;
            carry = digit > 9;
            c[--i] = (char)('0' + digit - 10 * carry);
        }
        if (carry) {
            memmove(c + 1, c, clen + 1);
            c[0] = '1';
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *a = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "123456890123456890123456890";
    const char *b = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "2035864230956204598237409822324";
    char *c = bigadd(a, b);
    printf("%s + %s = %s\n", a, b, c);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In function add(), or any function which may be called following to calling add() I do not use printf().

Comment: @DarekMajcherczyk: yes but you call `printf()` before and after `add()` in `UTEST138()`.

Comment: *Your code is extremely complicated, the presentation and indentation is inconsistent and the ubiquitous cramming of multiple instructions on the same line make it too difficult to follow.*  +1 for just that alone.